# Why is it called "border-width" when it sets the height of the border line, not the horizontal size?

Tags: html, css

I have just realized how counter-intuitive this is. Why does border-width sets the actual height of the border line? Why isn't it called border-height? Why is it called border-width when the actual width is not being changed?

I am not talking about the border going around the element. I am talking about the size of the border line. Width means horizontal size. Height means vertical. Border-width does not change the horizontal size of the border, it changes the height of the line, so why is it called border-width then? How is the width of the border line being changed?

Comment: border apply horizontally AND vertically so it's a width in one case and height in another. They made a choice, as simple as that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A border goes on all four sides of an element; there are two vertical borders and two horizontal borders.

- The horizontal borders you might size as "border-height"
- The vertical borders you might size as "border-width"

So it seems like it's a draw and that `border-width` was chosen arbitrarily. But it wasn't.

Note that while font-size sets the *height* of the glyph of a font, the principle of the em is that it is a square whose dimensions are based on the *width* of an uppercase M; [the "em" was the full width of a letter block](https://typography.guru/term/em-square-r46/)

Also consider that [width— not height— is often the default value for percentages in properties like padding, too](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-padding). You'll see in the earlier CSS specification that `padding-` properties all contained a "padding width value type". `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` took a value which was called a "padding width" — even though it's a vertical space.

So there is historical precedent for favoring the word `width` for length measurements over `height`, regardless that length being applied in the x or y axis. It likely started in typography and carried over into CSS *in general* where it was the deciding factor in calling it `border-width`.

Maybe a better term would have been `border-thickness`, but when size of your stylesheet matters, `border-width` is going to save you bytes over `height` and `thickness`. It's sheer speculation if this was a factor, but CSS was released when dial-up modems were still a thing, so it's entirely possible `border-width` was chosen not just because of precedent, but because it took up less space (and was also easier to type).